# AWS mysql multiquery syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, tomcat

I am porting a Tomcat7/Mysql applicationto AWS. I am seeing that whenever I send a multiple query statement I get an error like this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ....
```

I have only detyected it on multiple queries (f.e. Multiple related deletes, like "delete from xxx; delete from xxx"). Single queries seem to work correctly.

I am using this code for the connection.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?user=" + userName + "&password=" + password + "&autoReconnect=true&amp;allowMultiQueries=true";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
```

To run the query I have this code:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
res = st.executeQuery(query);
conn.commit();
```

I have already set the `allowMultiQueries=true` but it is not working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Is multiquery supported?

Comment: Why use & for some parameters but &amp; for others?

Comment: Inherited from previous code. That solved it.

Comment: Be sure you are aware of the exponentially-increased danger of SQL injection vulnerabilities when multiquery is enabled.  It is off by default for some very compelling reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @jarmod, the problem was in the url and the separator. I should use & instead of `&amp;`

```
&autoReconnect=true&allowMultiQueries=true
```